# How do I delete old folders from multiple subfolders in ADLS through ADF pipeline using delete activity?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am trying to delete folders that are older than 7 days from ADLS. The folders I want to delete have date as name and are under subfolders of the main folder. Please see below example for folder structure (raw is my container)

```
/raw/MainFolder/SubfolderA/20230430/File.csv
/raw/MainFolder/SubfolderA/20230415/File.csv
/raw/MainFolder/SubfolderA/20230410/File.csv

/raw/MainFolder/SubfolderB/20230430/File.csv
/raw/MainFolder/SubfolderB/20230420/File.csv
/raw/MainFolder/SubfolderB/20230405/File.csv
```

I need to delete all the folders that have the date as name and is more than 7 days old.
In this example the pipeline should delete 2 folders from SubFolderA (20230415, 20230410) and 2 folders from SubFolderB (20230420, 20230405).

How do I create a pipeline in Azure Data Factory that dynamically deletes these old folders using a GetMetadata and Delete Activity?

I created a pipeline with GetMetadata activity and am able to see the folders under MainFolder in debug output. But I need help with making it dynamic so that it will fetch all the folders under the subfolders and creating the delete activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to achieve your requirement like below.

This is my folder structure:

```
raw
    MainFolder
        SubfolderA
            20230425
                //files
            20230427
                //files
            20230429
                //files
            20230523
                //files
        SubfolderB
            20230425
                //files
            20230427
                //files
            20230429
                //files
            20230523
                //files
```

As you want to delete the folders which are more than 7 days old, first I have created a dates array using a ForEach with `@range(0,7)`. This expression gives the array`[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]`.

Inside ForEach I have used append variable activity to an array to append the date in `yyyyMMdd` format with the below expression.

```
@formatDateTime(subtractFromTime(utcNow(),item(),'Day'),'yyyyMMdd')
```

This gives the dates array for the last 7 days list as below.

[image]

This is my pipeline flow:

[image]

Use a Get Meta data activity first to get the subfolders list(`SubfolderA,SubfolderA`) and pass this child items array to ForEach.

- Inside ForEach, use another Get Meta data activity(in path give the `@item().name`) to get the date folders list.
- Now, use filter on these child items. Here we are filtering the date folders by checking our dates array contains the folder name or not.
- Get the child items which are more than 7 days from the filter. Here we need to iterate through this array. But ADF currently does not support nested Foreach. So, use Execute pipeline activity by passing the current subfolder name and its correspoding child items array.
- In the child pipeline, iterate through the child items and use delete activity on it.

**Use the dataset with a parameter like below:**

[image]

**My Parent pipeline JSON:**

```
{
    "name": "parent",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "get subfolders",
                "type": "GetMetadata",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "ForEach1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "sourcecsv",
                        "type": "DatasetReference",
                        "parameters": {
                            "folderpath": "MainFolder"
                        }
                    },
                    "fieldList": [
                        "childItems"
                    ],
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "iterate subfolders",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "get subfolders",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('get subfolders').output.childItems",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "get date folders",
                            "type": "GetMetadata",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "dataset": {
                                    "referenceName": "sourcecsv",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "folderpath": {
                                            "value": "@concat('MainFolder/',item().name)",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "fieldList": [
                                    "childItems"
                                ],
                                "storeSettings": {
                                    "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                    "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                },
                                "formatSettings": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Execute Pipeline1",
                            "type": "ExecutePipeline",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Filter1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "pipeline": {
                                    "referenceName": "child",
                                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                                },
                                "waitOnCompletion": true,
                                "parameters": {
                                    "date_folder": {
                                        "value": "@activity('Filter1').output.value",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    },
                                    "path": {
                                        "value": "@concat('MainFolder/',item().name)",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Filter1",
                            "type": "Filter",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "get date folders",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "items": {
                                    "value": "@activity('get date folders').output.childItems",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                },
                                "condition": {
                                    "value": "@not(contains(variables('daysarr'),item().name))",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@range(0,7)",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Append variable1",
                            "type": "AppendVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "daysarr",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@formatDateTime(subtractFromTime(utcNow(),item(),'Day'),'yyyyMMdd')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "counter": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "daysarr": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "temp": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "new": {
                "type": "Array"
            }
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "lastPublishTime": "2023-05-02T07:27:09Z"
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}
```

**Child Pipeline JSON:**

```
{
    "name": "child",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@pipeline().parameters.date_folder",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Delete1",
                            "type": "Delete",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "dataset": {
                                    "referenceName": "sourcecsv",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "folderpath": {
                                            "value": "@concat(pipeline().parameters.path,'/',item().name)",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "enableLogging": false,
                                "storeSettings": {
                                    "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                    "recursive": true,
                                    "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "date_folder": {
                "type": "array"
            },
            "path": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

**Folders before pipeline execution:**

[image]

You can see the folders which are more than 7 days folders were deleted after pipeline execution.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
If I wanted to change the scenario to delete folders older than 30 days or 45 days, what would I need to change?

Comment: just change the number from 7 to required number of days in array expression in first forEach activity from `@range(0,7)` to `@range(0,n)` which generates the dates array for last n dates. The remaining is same as above.

Comment: I think this is the best solution I got but I am not able to implement it because I am new to ADF. Would you be able to post a video or clear steps with all screenshots and expressions used in every step? Appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Use the Pipeline JSONs that I have provided above. Copy that JSONs in your pipelines and you can build yours. Those JSONs contains every activity and every expression. You can go through this [Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-get-started) to learn about ADF.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I used the JSON and created the pipelines. 
My parent pipeline is succeeding with all activities but the child pipeline is failing. I am using " @concat(pipeline().parameters.path,'/',item().name) " for folderpath expression.
I am using the same dataset in the delete activity that I used in the "get date folders" metadata activity. Am I doing something wrong?
It doesn't show me the correct error because the error is in the child pipeline.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: I can see the input of the child pipeline as below. I think it's passing  the right date folders to be deleted but I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: {
    "pipeline": {
        "referenceName": "child",
        "type": "PipelineReference"
    },
    "waitOnCompletion": true,
    "parameters": {
        "date_folder": [
            {
                "name": "20221215",
                "type": "Folder"
            },
            {
                "name": "20221231",
                "type": "Folder"
            }
        ],
        "path": "MainFolder/SubfolderA"
    }
}

Comment: In the child pipeline check whether the delete actvity `enableLogging` is set to true or False and make sure it is set to false. Can you provide picture of the error in the child pipeline. To get it Go to Monitor->Pipeline runs -> Child pipeline name. Here, it will show the child pipeline run and you can see the error message for the activity.

Comment: Logging is disabled. I haven't been able to publish it but I ran the child pipeline by passing the parameters manually. 
Parameters:
date_folder: [20221231]
path: MainFolder/SubfolderA

Here is the error:

The expression 'concat(pipeline().parameters.path,'/',item().name)' cannot be evaluated because property 'name' cannot be selected. Property selection is not supported on values of type 'Integer'.

Comment: The error is 

The required Blob is missing. Folder path: raw/MainFolder/SubfolderA/20221231/

But this path actually exists. I am not sure why adf is not able to find it.

Comment: I deployed it and ran. 
It is deleting the file inside the date folder but not the folder all together.
It shows success where a file exists inside the date folder and deletes the file. But it fails where a file does not exist in the date folder.
How can I get it to delete the folders?
Recursively option is enabled.
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: 'The error is The required Blob is missing' - make sure you are using ADLS Gen2 linked service. I think this error will arise when we try to delete an empty directory with Azure Blob storage linked service. In Blob storage we cannot have empty directories and thats why it will give this error. So better to use ADLS linked service.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following approach:

- Create a pipeline parameter ,say, `Iteration` with `Int` datatype and provide default value as -7 .
- Use ForEach activity and provide expression in the items as :

  `@createarray(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)`
- Inside foreach, use delete activity . In the source settings, point your dataset to `raw/MainFolder/` level and use wildcard file path, and expression like this:
  `@concat(addDays(utcNow(),add(pipeline().parameters.iteration,item()),'subFolder*/yyyyMMdd*'),'A.parquet')`

You can modify the above expression as per your file path .

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
1. How should I setup my dataset and GetMetadata activity for this to work?
2. For the file path in data set, can I give just until main folder?
3. Instead of SubfolderA and SubfolderB I have folders named with random names, how do I change the query to work with any folder name?

Comment: I am getting an error when I try this:

Wildcard filter is not supported if file name contains folder separators, e.g. '\' and '/'. Specify the folder part in folder path property instead.